# How can we send some file (attach files) through mail From jenkins post bulid Action

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I need to send some document or custom reports through mail after every successful build completion, through jenkins post build Action. how can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Archive your reports using the post build actions of jenkins.
Then use the [Email Ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to attach - again in the post build actions.